# Get user id with powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, user-accounts

I'm updating custom fields in a document library and I have to set a value for the person that's responsible for the file.
On the frontend I put the AD account name in the field but it is stored as a numeric user id. How can I get this id using powershell if I have the AD account name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb URLTOWEB    
$user = $web.EnsureUser("USERLOGINNAME")
$id = $user.ID
```

Now `$id` will contain the ID of the user

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom field. We don't know it's behavior. Probably, your field stores `SPUser.Id` property value. In this case method [`SPWeb.EnsureUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) helps you get `SPUser` object.